# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta en mongoose por rango de fechas?

Tags: json, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy desarrollando una página web full stack usando el Stack MERN; en este momento estoy tratando de realizar una búsqueda por rango de fechas.[image: Como se realiza el filtro desde el frontend]

En este punto los datos que ingreso en los campos están llegando correctamente al Backend y este es el código que se encarga de procesar la petición y regresar los datos que están almacenados en MongoDB.

```
list: async (req,res,next) => {
        try{
            //Guardando el rango de fechas
            const fechaInicial = req.body.fecha_inicial;
            const fechaFinal = req.body.fecha_final;
            console.log(fechaInicial)
            const reg = await models.find({'Fecha_Creacion': fechaInicial});
            if(!reg){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'El registro no existe'
                });
            }else{
                res.status(200).json(reg);
            }
        }catch (e) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Ocurrio un error'
            });
            next(e);        
        }
        
    }
```

Pero no he podido encontrar la forma de que se filtren los datos según la fecha inicial y la fecha final que fueron ingresados por el usuario.

Comment: Ahora he usado `const fechaInicial = new Date(req.body.fecha_inicial);`
            `const fechaFinal = new Date(req.body.fecha_final);` para convertir la fecha inicial y la fecha final en formato Date

Comment: Este es el formato de la fecha que se está almacenando en Mongo **2019-12-25T00:32:31.760Z**

Comment: Problema solucionado parcialmente `const reg = await models.find({'Fecha_Creacion':  { $gte: fechaInicial, $lte: fechaFinal}});`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta manera:

de esta manera  puedes filtrar entre dos fechas es decir buscar  entre dos Fechas de creación.

```
schema.find({
created_at: {
    $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
 }
})
```

Comment: Por favor amplía tu respuesta agregando detalles de cómo lo que propones ayuda al OP a resolver su problema. Para algunos puede ser clara tu respuesta pero la idea de stack overflow es servir de referencia para muchos visitantes que tengan un problema similar al del OP.

Answer (score 1):

Usa los operadores [$gte:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html) y [$lt:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) para obtener un rango de fechas. Te quedaría de esta forma

```
list: async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
      //Guardando el rango de fechas
      const fechaInicial = req.body.fecha_inicial;
      const fechaFinal = req.body.fecha_final;
      console.log(fechaInicial);
      const reg = await models.find({
         Fecha_Creacion: {
            $gte: fechaInicial,
            $lt: fechaFinal
         }
      });

      if (!reg) {
         res.status(404).send({
            message: 'El registro no existe'
         });
      } else {
         res.status(200).json(reg);
      }
   } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send({
         message: 'Ocurrio un error'
      });
      next(e);
   }
};
```